# Python csv.reader csv excel and special sign

Tags: python, csv

I try to import a table with special sign (I need them to print it). It is written in excel (German), delimiter=';', newline=''. The special sign are signs like: °();. ä,ö,ü ;

```
csvfile = open("Test.csv")
data = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=';')
```

I have tried several modifcation (like encoding)- which I have found here and in google - put nothing works.
Did anybody know whats wrong in my code?

Thanks

Comment: How are you printing it? Are you printing it to a console? Unix or Windows?

Comment: I print with reportlab (It is a table which should be put in latex)
win 8.1
latex using pythontex
and python2.7

Comment: basic concept: your data are encoded. find out which encoding was used to encode your data. decode from that encoding into Unicode on input to your program. keep everything in Unicode throughout the program. on output from your program encode preferably using utf-8 as it's a good combo of memory usage and lang support

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import csv

def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
# csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader =       csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                        dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')
```

May be Unicode issue
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks, but I recived this error code:
def unicode_csv_reader(’Test.csv’, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: don't pass csv file to function .. Check the link for more clarification